# How do I install drivers for Asus PCE-N53 wireless adapter?

Tags: wireless, drivers, asus

I just installed this wireless card into my build, but Ubuntu doesnt recognize it. I have the CD it came with but no optical drive. I was wondering how else I could install the drivers? I've never used Ubuntu before this computer so I have absolutely no experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!